# Determinant For ELO Rating.

Tags: probability, functions, probability-distributions, special-functions

I'm trying to implement a variant of the ELO system, for a game I'm working on. 
Giving two players $A$ and $B$ with ratings $R_A$ and $R_B$ respectively, the expectation of $A; E_A$ is given by the formula: $$E_A = \frac{1}{1+10^{\frac{R_B-R_A}{Y}}}\tag{*}$$

The Expectation of $B$ is similarly given by: $$E_B = \frac{1}{1+10^{\frac{R_A-R_B}{Y}}}$$

The different possible game outcomes are given scores:
A win is $1.0$, a loss is: $0.0$, and a draw is $0.5$. The actual score of $A$ is $S_A$.

After a match between $A$ and $B$, the new ranking of $A; R'_A$ is given by: 
$$R'_A = R_A + K(S_A - E_A)$$

Question: For any value of $Y$, what value of $K$ should I choose, such that that value is a **constant** and makes the player's rating as reliable as possible.

I'm currently using $K = \sqrt{Y}$

$(*)$ Most Chess ELO algorithms use a value of $Y = 400$

Comment: The $*$ was meant to provide information. -_-

Comment: Look at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Suggest an edit.

Comment: As for the question: Wiki has a discussion on the $K$ value problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system#Mathematical_issues (though only for $Y=400$)

Comment: I read it. $K$ values were seemingly chosen arbitrarily without a mathematical explanation. Also most organisations used different $K$ values for different ranges. Furthermore, due to the pecularities of my game system, I don't use $400$.

Comment: I don't think there is an optimal value here (otherwise it would be used) thats why it's placed in the "Mathematical problems" section. For your question it might be useful to note that the particular value of $Y$ is related to the distribution of scores. If we scale the scores $R$ by a factor of $k$ and scale $Y$ and $K$ by the same factor then the new ranking system would work just the same as the old just with scores a factor $k$ larger.

Comment: What about a near optimal value?

Comment: I don't know, it would think it requires trial-and-error for the particular game, but maybe someone else here has some better ideas. But in general I can say that making an optimal ranking system for such games is almost impossible unless everybody plays against a computer that plays the same against everybody. Scores will depend on the pool of players you have, if they can choose who to play and not to play, ... For example we can have a closed group of people playing each other and getting scores in that group better than the best player in the world no matter what value of $K$ you choose.

Comment: btw you can find some more info about why the $K$ values in ELO was picked like they are now here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system#Combatting_deflation

Comment: @Winther I don't think a closed group is possible. The winner takes scores from the loser. If the difference between their rankings reaches a certain point, no points will be gained for the stronger player. I expect that the max ELO score for such a group is a function of the size of the group, and is proportional to it(assuming everyone in the group starts with the same score.

Comment: @Winther My system won't have the issues of players refusing to participate in competitions to shore up their ratings. I will use an aging function which decreases player's ratings as a Geometric Progression with $r: r \le 1$ as the number of points decreased per unit time. I'm thinking of setting their minimum rating to be 'aged' to, as $R_A^x: E(A) = \frac {3}{4}$ where $R_A = $ rating before start of aging session.

Comment: You might get a better response if you try asking this at [Game Development Stack Exchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). They seem to have some questions there about scoring systems: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=scoring+systems

Comment: You might be interested in freechess.org's "[Glicko Ratings System](http://www.freechess.org/Help/HelpFiles/glicko.html)"